# Find limit of ceiling $x^3$ using squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to check if my answer is correct. The question is to use the squeeze theorem to find the $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\lceil x^3 \rceil}{x^3 + 100}$

My solution:

$$x^3 < \lceil x^3 \rceil \leq x^3+1$$
$$\frac{x^3}{x^3+100} < \frac{\lceil x^3 \rceil}{x^3 + 100} \leq \frac{x^3+1}{x^3+100}$$ 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^3}{x^3+100} = 1$$ 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^3 + 1}{x^3+100} = 1$$
$$\therefore \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\lceil x^3 \rceil}{x^3 + 100} = 1$$ 
Am I doing this right?

Comment: It seems alright to me.

Comment: Very nitpicky: depending on the course you're taking you could explain in more detail why $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^3}{x^3+100} = 1$ by a method of your choice.

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: @Hirshy okay got it! Thanks guys!